# EF6 Many to Many Relationship: SqlException: Invalid column name 'SubAccount_SubAccountID'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm getting an error while loading my data from Entity Framework EF6 with:

***SqlException: Invalid column name 'SubAccount_SubAccountID'.***

This is my query to EF6:

```
var subAccounts = Context
            .SubAccount
            .Include(i => i.Users)
            .ToList();
```

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EzC5.png)

this ICollation Users is a many to many relationship using Fluent API.

This is the Fluent API configuration in the UserConfiguration class:

```
HasMany(p => p.SubAccounts)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("UserID");
                mc.MapLeftKey("SubAccountID");
                mc.ToTable("MOB_USER_SUBACCOUNT");
            });
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

It will guide you trough the configuration of a Many To Many relationship, using EF6 Code First and Fluent Api